# 404 error add marker using leaflet on a xpage

Tags: javascript, leaflet, xpages

Using leaflet I'm getting 404 error when trying to add a marker. The URL it trying to get is "https://Host.com/Application.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/.css/images/marker-icon.png"
It's on IBM Domino 9.0.1 FP8 system, using XPages.  Not sure how to change the ICON url to point to different correct location ?

Thanks
Bob

Comment: Pal, there are [tutorials](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/) for this.

Comment: The URL you've written reply with a 404 error by the way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change leaflet marker icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590102/change-leaflet-marker-icon)

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

What solved the problem as where to locate or the correct URL to images from a LeafLet while using IBM Domino XPages.  Is to defined a virtual folder for the images in the Resource/Images.  Then reference that folder as the Icon.default.ImagePath.
Thanks to Tommy Valand who posted originally on virtual folder.